# How to create a new object in VB with a name taken from a variable

Tags: vb.net, oop

Good evening,

How do I create a new object in VB with the identifier/name taken from a variable.

Basically I want to pass a string (jobID) to a subroutine and in that I want it to create an object which is called whatever the string is.

So say `jobID = "142sds2"` I want it to effectively run `dim 142sds2 as new object`.

I have tried:

```
Public Sub newObject(jobID As String)

Dim jobID As New PhotoJob

End Sub
```

But this didn't work.

I'm relatively new to VB (but have a middling level of experience with C++ and Java) so any help would be appreciated, but please bare in mind my newness :P

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you want the id of the new object to come from a value in a string you can't do it. VB.NET is a statically compiled language.

Comment: also jobID should probably more rightly be a property of said object.  otherwise var names cannot start with a numeral

Comment: The better way to approach this is with a `Dictionary(Of String, PhotoJob)`.

Comment: Hang on... so what I am trying to achieve is a program that manages a bunch of tasks. I've created a class for each task (PhotoJob) and it has a whole bunch of properties. Is there any way that every time I add a new task, I can create a new instance of this object? Sorry, as I said, I'm by no means an expert.

Comment: And can you please explain that dictionary thing?

Comment: [Dictionary(Of TKey, TValue)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508(v=vs.110).aspx)  create a task, add to the dictionary using the string  as the key to get it back

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a dictionary:

```
Dim photoJobs As New Dictionary(Of String, PhotoJob)()
'...
photoJobs.Add(jobID, new PhotoJob())
```

Reference the created object like this:

```
photoJobs(jobID).SomeProperty
photoJobs(jobID).SomeMethod()

For Each job in photoJobs
   job.Value.SomeMethod()
Next
```

Comment: Ahh ok, I've never used a dictionary before. How would I then go about accessing the properties and methods of each entry in the dictionary (as defined by the PhotoJobs class)? I appreciate your help